# bootstrap navbar-static-top menu breaks on two lines

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I encountered a problem with the bootstrap navbar.

I Made menu using the navbar-static-top - at first it was all good. When menu was expanded and few items added, and now with the width before to collapse, it is spreading into two lines that looks awful. In CSS bootstrap'a dig deeper, but without much success. Please help, how to be here?

Currently it looks like shown here:
[image]

Navbar code:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="bright-logo-text navbar-brand" href="index.html">Clipboard Stripper</a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Features<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="screenshots.html">Screenshots</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="usage.html">Usage</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>


            <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="screenshots.html">Screenshots</a></li>
            <!--li class="active"><a href="usage.html">Usage</a></li-->
            <li><a href="download.html">Download</a></li>
            <li><a href="purchase.html">Purchase</a></li>
            <!--li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              </ul>
            </li-->
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/mk57S/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/mk57S/1/)

Answer (score 12):

I also wanted to use it through CSS without redownloading and customizing Bootstrap, `Skelly` answer is working fine on `Bootstrap 3` but in my case `Bootstrap 3.2` the CSS changed a litte... Here is an updated version of all CSS required

```
    @media (max-width:992px){
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
     }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
     }
     .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You say this works for Bootstrap 3.2. I suppose it also works for Bootstrap 3?

Comment: For Bootstrap 3.0, look at `Skelly` answer on top.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22228476/1212166

Comment: So this solution will NOT work with 3.0? It'd be nice to have a solution that works accross the board, if at all possible

Comment: Your question is a little awkward, you can only use 1 version at a time so...you use 3.0 or 3.2, just choose the one you want?!? But whatever, my solution should work for both anyway, just didn't try it

Comment: That's what I wanted to know, thanks. The idea is that I have 3.0 now but will probably get 3.2 later, so I'd like the solution to be forward compatible...

Answer (score 11):

You can have it collapse sooner using a CSS media query. The default breakpoint is 768px. Here we change it to 990 pixels so that it collapses before the 2-line wrapping starts..

```
@media (max-width: 990px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/119436

Comment: Thanks, it works. But there is small diference between nav button postion in sizes from 992 to 768 and less than 768. If size is between from 992 to 768 yhe nav button has no margin at right. You can se it here: [http://jsfiddle.net/mk57S/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/mk57S/1/)

Comment: Latest bootstrap - use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25857699/897326). With the above CSS collapse menu/dropdown does not work properly.