# How to stop Bootstrap navabar using two lines (wrapping) when using a responsve links menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have implemented a responsive links menu like the one described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420151/manipulate-jquery-menu-on-re-size-for-responsive-layout) question.

The problem is that when I resize the window at certain breakpoints the element with `id='search-facility'` wraps onto two lines like the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228239/bootstrap-navbar-static-top-menu-breaks-on-two-lines) otherwise the `.navabar` and menu behave as expected.

I have tried changing the breakpoints as describe in other answers but this has not worked.

How can I stop the navbar from wrapping onto two lines?

Is there a way to fire a JavaScript  function before the Bootstrap media breakpoints?

**Html**

```
<div id="navigation" class="top-bar-navigation navbar-fixed-top">
<!-- NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="main-nav-collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul id="links-container" class="nav navbar-nav" style="min-width: 75px;">


                <li class="link-li"> <a href="#" class="link">Some Link</a></li>
                <li class="link-li"> <a href="#" class="link">Some Link</a></li>
                <li class="link-li"> <a href="#" class="link">Some Link</a></li>
            <li class="link-li"> <a href="#" class="link">Some Link</a></li>
        <li class="link-li"> <a href="#" class="link">Some Link</a></li>

                <li id="search-fa" class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Search Stuff<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul id="overflow" class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="form-group"><a href="#"><input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search Stuff" /></a></li>

                        <li id="search-submenu" class="dropdown-submenu">
                            <ul id="search-submenu-results" class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li class="dropdown-header">Search Results</li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider" style="min-width: 170px"></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>

            <div id="search-container" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="quick-search" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" style="background-color:#fff;border-radius:0px"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="display: none; position: absolute; min-width: 100%"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).resize(function () {

    var navbarWidth = parseInt($("#search-container").offset().left - $("#links-container").offset().left);

    var appsWidth = parseInt($("#links-container").outerWidth());

    // If links are wider than available space move to dropdown else move back onto navbar

    var apps = $("li.link-li:not(li.search-submenu-result)").toArray();
    var appsToRelocate = [];

    if (appsWidth > 0 && navbarWidth > 0) {
        if (appsWidth > navbarWidth) {

            while (appsWidth > navbarWidth) {

                var app = apps.pop();

                appsWidth -= $(app).outerWidth();

                appsToRelocate.push(app);
            }

            _.each(appsToRelocate, function (value, key, list) {
                $("#overflow").append($(value).remove());
            });

        }
        else {

            while (apps.length > 0 && appsWidth < navbarWidth) {

                var app = apps.pop();

                appsWidth += $(app).outerWidth();

                // check if another app can fit else break;

                if (appsWidth < navbarWidth) {
                    appsToRelocate.push(app);
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }

            _.each(appsToRelocate.reverse(), function (value, key, list) {
                $(value).remove().insertBefore("#search-fa");
            });
        }
    }

    $("#links-container").css("visibility", "visible");
});
```

**JSFiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/clDjs/z7Lke6ys/5/

**UPDATE**

Adding  `clear: none; height: 0` to the `ul.links-container` stops the two line issue.

https://jsfiddle.net/clDjs/z7Lke6ys/6/

Comment: Can you provide a working example?

Comment: why are your links `visibility:hidden`? i mean why not `display: none;`

Comment: @reenleedr because I need to be able to calculate the outer width when the view is rendered to know how many to move. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921428/dom-element-width-before-appended-to-dom

Comment: @clD earnestly i didn't get what you are trying to do.. but i think my i answer will help understand the problem's cause.

Comment: @Dekel Ive added a working copy

Answer (score 0):

This double line issue is due to `<ul>` which is using the `width: auto` and since `#search-facility` is `float: right` therefore it will by default be pulled down by `ul` as shown in image below:

[image]

so the quick fix for this problem is to replace `visibility: hidden` and `display: none` and after break point set it back to `block` or `initial`

but i think you should give search box a fixed width and then use `calc()` function to calculate the width of `ul` or instead use `%` approach.

Comment: That makes no difference. I have added an example.